# Slicing arrays based on relations in the data (in Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, slice, chunks

I have arrays in this form: `[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 7, 6]` and I need to slice them into something like `[[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 4], [1], [7, 7, 6]]`, where breaks are determined by the absolute difference between consecutive pairs being larger than 1.

Is there in Ruby some magic that I can harness, or am I left with having to code a plain old iteration?

Comment: @Stefan has a good answer, but why the rush to make a selection? Why not give some time for others (who are now working on answers) to make other suggestions. btw, `slice_when` (and maybe `slice_after`) is quite new (Ruby 2.2 I believe).

Comment: Stefan's answer works and points at the correct docs (2.2.2), that's all you need for an answer to this type of question to be accepted. The version point is moot: if someone is not using that particular version and has an alternative solution that works, they are welcome to post it, and readers will benefit from those, as well as from Stefan's. As for what constitutes the "best" answer, that we can argue on all day long, but I believe there is no unique metric by which to determine "bestness".

Comment: Had I posted the question, I too would have selected @Stefan's answer, but I would have waited at least a couple of hours before doing so. As to when `slice_when` became available, I was merely informing you and other readers who may be unfamiliar with the freshly-minted method. I just don't like quick-draw selections. They can discourage other, sometimes better, sometimes thought-provoking, answers and (imo) are discourteous to those still preparing answers. (The greenie was already up when I began preparing my answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 7, 6]
a.slice_when { |i, j| (i - j).abs > 1 }.to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 4], [1], [7, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: Yay! I knew there was something :) (I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work with Ruby v1.9+:

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 7, 6]

arr[1..-1].each_with_object([[arr.first]]) do |e,a|
  ((a.last.last-e).abs > 1) ? a << [e] : a[-1] << e
end
  #=> [[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 4], [1], [7, 7, 6]]
```

If you need to support earlier versions, you can use `reduce` rather than `each_with_object`.

Comment: How would you use reduce, exactly?

Comment: @Morpheu5 `arr[1..-1].reduce([[arr.first]]) do |a,e| ; ((a.last.last-e).abs > 1) ? a << [e] : a[-1] << e ; a ; end`.